# Combine multiple tables with different date values

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the title indicates, I want to create a view that combines multiple tables with different dates. 
The tables are as follow : (examples)

OutlookEmailsPerDay :

[image]

OutlookAttachmentsPerDay :

[image]

OutlookSyncPerDay :

[image]

OutlookSentEmailsPerDay :

[image]

Based on the ComputerSystemId, I want to join those tables to get a result similar to the one in this question :
[SQL - Combine two tables with different date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737577/sql-combine-two-tables-with-different-date-value)
Does the same approach work for more than two tables. I know I can combine two tables then add another and so on, but is it possible to do it in one step?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select *
from OutlookEmailsPerDay emails
inner join OutlookAttachmentsPerDay attachments on emails.ComputerSystemId = attachments.ComputerSystemId
inner join OutlookSyncPerDay sync on emails.ComputerSystemId = sync.ComputerSystemId 
inner join OutlookSentEmailsPerDay sent on sent.ComputerSystemId  = emails.ComputerSystemId
```

Comment: thanks but this is not what I want, pleae see the SO question I mentioned

Comment: Yes you can use that logic, but you can simply use a `Full outer join` for this like, `select *
from OutlookEmailsPerDay emails
full outer join OutlookAttachmentsPerDay attachments on emails.DateProd = attachments.DateProd` , this way you can get all the records from both the tables irrespective of the field in ON clause